# How to send data between php pages using javascript

Tags: php

I have a variable called messages and I want to pass the value of message(text area) from template.php to sendmessage.php ( text area ) using javascript. Would you please help with this?

Regards,

Comment: first search here...there a a lots of similar questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ajax to pick value of DOM elements or you can use location.href with the value you want to send appended to the url .
Ex: http://localhost/message/index.php?&message=$('#message').val()

Hope this will help !!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of whatever redirect you're currently using, modify it to a Javascript redirect. Try changing your link to something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function newLoc() {
    var messages = "something"; //set up the messages variable
    window.location = "sendmessage.php?messages=" + messages;
  }
</script>

<a href="#" onclick="newLoc()">Click Here</a>
```